# phantomjs and chrome return different data when calling canvas.toDataURL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, base64, phantomjs

I'm cropping an image using canvas

```
function crop(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 20;
    canvas.height = 20;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 20, 20);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

However, when I compare the base64 data return by Chrome and PhantomJs I noticed they're different. Does anyone know why this is ?

Comment: Where is `img` being set?

Comment: in this case I use gif (the input is base64 too)

Answer (score 0):

It's a Phantomjs issue and there's a working-arround solution. Take a look this:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10455